# convert character column and then split it into multiple new boolean columns using r mutate

Tags: r, data-cleaning, dplyr

I am attempting to split out a flags column into multiple new columns in r using mutate_at and then separate functions.  I have simplified and cleaned my solution as seen below, however I am getting an error that indicates that the entire column of data is being passed into my function rather than each row individually. Is this normal behaviour which just requires me to loop over each element of x inside my function? or am I calling the mutate_at function incorrectly?

example data:

```
dataVariable <- data.frame(c_flags = c(".q.q.q","y..i.o","0x5a",".lll.."))
```

functions:

```
dataVariable <- read_csv("...",
  col_types = cols(
    c_date = col_datetime(format = ""),
    c_dbl = col_double(),
    c_flags = col_character(),
    c_class = col_factor(c("a", "b", "c")),
    c_skip = col_skip()
))


funTranslateXForNewColumn <- function(x){
    binary = ""
    if(startsWith(x, "0x")){
        binary=hex2bin(x)
    } else {
        binary = c(0,0,0,0,0,0)
        splitFlag = strsplit(x, "")[[1]]
        for(i in splitFlag){
          flagVal = 1
          if(i=="."){
            flagVal = 0
          }
          binary=append(binary, flagVal)
        }
    }
    return(paste(binary[4:12], collapse='' ))
}



mutate_at(dataVariable, vars(c_flags), funs(funTranslateXForNewColumn(.)))

separate(dataVariable, c_flags, c(NA, "flag_1","flag_2","flag_3","flag_4","flag_5","flag_6","flag_7","flag_8","flag_9"), sep="")
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
Warning messages:
1: Problem with `mutate()` input `c_flags`.
i the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

After translating the string into an appropriate binary representation of the flags, I will then use the seperate function to split it into new columns.

Comment: and what is your expected output for the data shared ? There should be a better way to do this than a `for` loop.

Comment: the flags are a string concatenation of true false values where . means false and any other value means true.       

the same column also includes some hex values that I also translate into binary.

The full functions looks at whether or not its a hex value and appropriately converts both into a binary string with a length of 9.

this binary string will then be split into different columns with each character having its own column

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the outcome I desired by replacing the mutate_at function with:

```
dataVariable$binFlags <- mapply(funTranslateXForNewColumn, dataVariable$c_flags)
```

However I want to know how to use the mutate_at function correctly.

credit to: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/41964/mutate-with-custom-function-in-r-does-not-work

The above link also includes the solution to get this function to work which is to vectorize the function:

```
v_funTranslateXForNewColumn <- Vectorize(funTranslateXForNewColumn)
mutate_at(dataVariable, vars(c_flags), funs(v_funTranslateXForNewColumn(.)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to OP's logic but maybe shorter :

```
dataVariable$binFlags <- sapply(strsplit(dataVariable$c_flags, ''), function(x)
                                 paste(as.integer(x != '.'), collapse = ''))
```

If you want to do this using `dplyr` we can implement the same logic as :

```
library(dplyr)

dataVariable %>%
  mutate(binFlags = purrr::map_chr(strsplit(c_flags, ''), 
                     ~paste(as.integer(. != '.'), collapse = '')))

#  c_flags binFlags
#1  .q.q.q   010101
#2  y..i.o   100101
#3  .lll..   011100
```

`mutate_at`/`across` is used when you want to apply a function to multiple columns. Moreover, I don't see here that you are creating only one new binary column and not multiple new columns as mentioned in your post.

Comment: I simplified my code for the post. The real data has some values already in hex which can easily be translated to binary. The function handles both cases.  

I then use: separate(dataVariable, c_flags, c(NA, "flag_1","flag_2","flag_3","flag_4","flag_5","flag_6","flag_7","flag_8","flag_9"), sep="")

Comment: not sure if I understand. This seems to give the same output as your code. Maybe update the example similar to your actual data.